# How to install pip for a total newbie

Tags: python, macos, pip, kernel, atom-editor

I have read a bunch of posts here and on Google, but my question is far more basic than the answers: If Python(2.7) came pre-installed on my MacBook Pro (High Sierra), can I just do `sudo easy_install pip` (as suggested) from the command line--withOUT causing issues? I have a vague understanding of global/local installations, and my understanding is certain Python installations aren't compatible with local/global kernel installations. I hope I am getting the terminology right, but I saw several warnings about installing pip for "a homebrew based python installation", but I am not sure whether Python on my laptop is installed via homebrew (nor how to find out).

My question came about because I wanted to install the Hydrogen package to use in Atom, the text editor (to help me learn Python). I finally succeeded in installing Hydrogen, but got stumped by the missing kernels (not sure which ones I need, so I am willing to install them all). But I can't seem to install the kernels without pip. So here I am.

My apologies for asking such a basic question--and thanks!

Comment: 1) Tumbleweed. Maybe ask the question on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)? 2) An advice from another newbie - don't start learning Python with Python 2.7. Install Python 3.6 instead. They really differ and you won't come across 2.x that often.

Comment: Oh, and wouldn't the tag `macos` be rather useful here?

Comment: Thought I tagged macos, but honestly wasn't sure if  (or how) this is related to MacOS or Atom or Hydrogen.

Comment: @YCode  You want the macos tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb is: *If your operating system has a package manager, use it.*

Unfortunately, MacOS is the only UNIX-like operating system that does *not* come with a decent package managment system.
(There is the app store, but that is useless for a lot open source software for several different reasons. It's also a walled garden.)

You have several choices (in descreasing suitability):

1. Use one of the [package managers available for MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#macOS_(OS_X)). Which one is the best choice for you depends on all the packages you need being available.
2. Use a [Python distribution](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDistributions). I've used Anaconda on ms-windows, and that has saved me a lot of hassle. A good choice if you are *only* looking for Python and related libraries.
3. Build everything yourself. This can be very time-consuming and is a duplication of effort. You will learn a lot though.

I would second Piinthesky's comment that you install Python 3.6. Python 2.7 is now a legacy version.

Answer (score 1):

Well although I am no Mac expert I've given it a shot anyway:

Yes you could but do you really want to risk it (or even do it)?

Mac-OS must rely on Python to fulfill something in the OS otherwise it would not come inbuilt. This means two things:

The Python installation will be minimal.  By that I mean it will have things missing (any large library for a start).  They will do this mainly to cut down on the OS size.  Therefore you will not have the full Python library and in the long term you may end up missing out.

Second if anything went wrong (IE you broke your installation or even modified it -yep I've done this in Linux and have ended up factory resetting) then you may cause something to stop working and may need to factory reset or perform some other drastic action on your OS.  A separate installation would prevent your from risking this.  This is very useful because there comes a time when you may decide to update certain modules with `pip` and find it can't or it updates something that you shouldn't be messing with.

Yes it's possible you may run into compatibility problems but I think it's most widely accepted that you do not use the inbuilt one as it needs to remain unchanged if the OS is to use it correctly.  Messing with it increases the chances of it breaking.

Conclusion:  So even though installing modules with `pip` (and getting `pip`) can be done with the inbuilt Python it comes down whether you want to risk harming your OS.  I strongly suggest you get a separate installation and leave the inbuilt one as it is.  Second as you mentioned you will find that the inbuilt versions are never up-to-date or are built were they are not really compatible with standard libraries (expect things like the missing runtime libraries all the time) , just another reason to stay clear of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem-for those newbies who just want Hydrogen to work:

1. Installed Python 3 (instead of messing around with Python 2.7 and pip).
2. Followed instructions here (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line) for 'get-pip.py'.
3. In Atom, cmd+shift+p to bring up the packages menu, clicked on 'Hydrogen Run', which gave me the errors again.
4. Copied the code from the warnings and installed the kernels needed (via the command line).
5. Hydrogen is now working.
   Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: I particularly think agree with the "Installed Python 3 (instead of messing around with Python 2.7 and pip)." part.  My experience has told me don't mess with the minimal interpreters.

Comment: There seems to be some instability with (some) kernels when I run Hydrogen--sometimes Hydrogen works, sometimes it doesn't respond--not even sure which part of the system/program this relates to.